# sync korganizer with google calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar, korganizer

You know that calendar that pops up when you click on the time in the panel?
I like it but I tend to keep all my events in google calendar. korganizer version is 4.4.11

Is there a way that I can get my google calendar to sync with this panel-clock calendar?

thanks

**EDIT:1**
It looks like what I need to do is sync google calendar with korganizer and that should do the trick, from what I understand.

**EDIT:2**
some answers here suggest I need this plug-in

```
sudo apt-get install akonadi-kde-resource-googledata
```

but they give no explanation on how to configure it once installed.

Comment: so you are using a KDE desktop ? Don't ever forget about providing proper information.The information will help you to get more answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by :

**=>** Open KOrganizer and navigate to Calendars  (Configure KOrganizer- General- Calendars)

**=>** Click on ADD Select `DAV Groupware Resource`

[image]

**=>** `Akonadi_davgroupware_resource`  will popup, click `Cancel`.

[image]

**=>** Now you will be able to add `Akonadi Resource` manually.

[image]
**=>**  Under Add server configuration, choose `CalDAV`. Remote URL format is "https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/Calender_ID/events/ . Personal calendar_id is usually your `Gmail Address` . 
you're done.

Source:  [ossrocks](http://ossrocks.blogspot.in/2012/02/sync-korganizer-and-google-calendar.html)

Comment: thank you @Jai it looks like I have groupdav but not caldav. do i need to install a plugin? korganizer version 4.4.11

Comment: @JoshuaRobison The version of Korganizer is 4.9.4 and Using Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Thanks @Jai . I got it working. I just had to find my ical file on the google calendar website and just add a new calendar in korganizer that syncs to the ical file. works like a charm. Wouldn't have been able to do it without your answer here - though the technique I used was not exactly the same.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison I am glad that you have got it. It will be helpful to other users If you add your way i mean how you did it.Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Akonadi (and thus KOrganizer) have direct support for Google Calendar now.

1. Go to Settings -> Configure KOrganizer
   [image: Press "General" -> "Calendars" tab -> Add]
2. In Settings: Press "General" -> "Calendars" tab -> Add
   [image: Press "General" -> "Calendars" tab -> Add]
3. Search for "Google" and press "Google Calendars and Tasks"
   [image: Search for "Google" and press "Google Calendars and Tasks"]
4. Press "Add" and sign in to your google account

Answer (score 1):

1. In Kontact, choose 'settings' in the pull-down menu at the top.
2. Select 'configure kontact'
3. Under the Calendar subheading highlight "general"
4. in the right half of the windo choose the "Calendars" tab
5. select "add"
6. in the popup window select ICal Calendar FILE
7. in the next popup window you need to enter the Filename and your desired display NAME.
   the display NAME is whatever you want it to be. The filename you have to go to your 
   google account and look it up. Next step
8. Log into your gmail account. In chrome (and other browsers these days?) you want to 
   select the 'google apps' dialog. In chrome this is up in the upper right near your 
   profile pic and it looks like an array of small boxes.
   9  In the popup select (google) calendar.
9. In the left pane of the calendar window you'll see a subheading "my calendars". 
   Mouse over the name of your google calendar. As it turns blue, a pull-down arrow
   appears. Click that and then select 'calendar settings'.
10. In the calendar settings screen you'll see details on your google calendar. 8
    headings down is "private address". Click on the bright green "ICAL" box and you'll 
    see a URL link. Copy and paste this link, verbatim, into the "Filename" box in the 
    kontact calendar settings dialog mentioned in step #7.