# How to add event in Ubuntu calendar?

Tags: indicator

I tried to add an event in Ubuntu 13.10 default calendar using the "add event" option. When I press that button, nothing happens. Can anyone tell me a solution to this?

Comment: I'm experiencing this, too. I don't know, this seems to be a bug. Look [→ here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) for further instructions about this.

Answer (score 2):

for ubuntu 20.4 users , you must install [gnome-calender from snap store](https://snapcraft.io/gnome-calendar) to use the add event feature

Answer (score 1):

The **"Add Event..."** button seems to be a vestigial feature from when Ubuntu used **Evolution Mail** instead of **Thunderbird Mail**, which is used today.

To be able to use that button again, I think, you'll have to install **Evolution Mail and Calendar** from the **Software Center**.

Comment: I have intalled Evolution Mail. There were other similar application as you mentioned>>

Evolution Mail and Calander
Evolution Mail

Then also nothing matters.

Comment: I thought the missing calendar was just the problem because one isn't installed by default. I don't know anymore. Sorry.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install evolution`. Then open evolution calendar & add some events. It will appear under clock menu.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Korganizer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/korganizer/), the calendar of KDE. It is available in ubuntu software center. In addition, you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267187/sync-korganizer-with-google-calendar) instructions to sync this calendar with google calendar (if you are interested in).

Answer (score 0):

As per best of my knowledge, adding online accounts from Settings -> Online accounts, will integrate all such features like calendar, email etc.

Please have a look at the screen shot attached herewith.

Regards.

[image]

Comment: Well, the icons are apparent, aren't they? I do not think, with icons, any one needs to recognize the text.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to link your calendar with an 'online account', like google.
You can use google calendar online : https://calendar.google.com, or use it under your android device for examples, it will be synchronized with your ubuntu calendar.

In addition to be able to add some local events into your pc, you will be able to have a shared and synchronized event between all your devices.