# Why can't I get Korganiser to load my google calendar?

Tags: calendar

I was hoping to use my existing Google Calendar and have decided that Korganiser seems to be well thought of for doing this sort of thing.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and am a very new user to this, which is my first experience of Linux at all.

I have installed KOrganizer v 4.13.3

I have tried adding my Google Calendar in Settings, Configure KOrganizer, General, Calendars by adding Google Calendars and Tasks, but I keep getting the message "Google Calendars and Tasks (not configured) Can't access KWallet.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think I have found an answer to this now here http://askubuntu.com/a/442119/530249

Comment: Now I would like KOrganizer to load my tasks from Google Calendar but I can't see how to do this as there is no ical address for tasks.